# Issue with setting TensorFlow as the session in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

Performing the following:

```
from keras import backend as K
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
```

Even though I've imported Keras and TensorFlow correctly, I get the following:

```
module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_session'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I know that I can do this via: "~/.keras/keras.json" but there must be a more dynamic way to doing this rather than modifying this file, trying the environment variable method within Python code doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 8):

Requires `.compat.v1.` after the `tf`

Example:

```
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config));
```

(Tested in Anaconda, Python 3.7, tensorflow 2.0.0)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need this :

```
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
```

Use it like this :

```
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend.set_session(sess)
```

Works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

# Set the config values 
config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=<NUM_PARALLEL_EXEC_UNITS>, 
inter_op_parallelism_threads=2, allow_soft_placement=True, device_count = {'CPU': 
<NUM_PARALLEL_EXEC_UNITS> })

#Create the session
session = tf.Session(config=config)
tf.keras.backend.set_session(session)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work for tensorflow 2.0.0

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
cfg = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to previous answers, unless you want to specify what GPU Tensorflow needs to use, you do not need to define what GPU to run. As it is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927644/9212050), Tensorflow will by default use a GPU available.